# Why should you care about a NAMED mutex not getting released in case of crash/exception?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex

```
[TestClass]
public class TestMutex{
   private Mutex myMutex = new Mutex(true, "MyMutex");

   [TestInitialize]
   public void Setup(){
      myMutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
   }
   [TestCleanup]
   public void Cleanup()
   {
     myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void Test_Mutex1(){
     [...do something...] }

   [TestMethod]
   public void Test_Mutex2(){
     [...do something else...] }
```

What this code does, is creating a Mutex named "MyMutex" and aquiring it before each method, as well as releasing it when finished.

Now if the Mutex gets hold by Test_Mutex1() and this method causes an exception or crashes, it never gets released since TestCleanup does not get called when exception happened.

Test_Mutex2() will never run since the wait handle returns false because the mutex was not released by Test_Mutex1().

=> Does this affect ANYTHING else besides Test_Mutex2() ?

=> Are there sideeffects on methods from other TestClasses ?

=> **Why should I care about releasing the mutex, besides I want to make Test_Mutex2() run?** It is a NAMED mutex, so there is no chance that at any other part of any code this blocks something as long as it is not explicitly named - did I get this right?

=> Is it **possible** (in general) that with above approach there can be a deadlock of any sort? I thought not, because it is NAMED and any other processes should not care about this.

Comment: This may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/mutexes

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not find any information about what happens in my described case

Comment: Yes, you do. In that article, read the section about "Abandonned Mutexes". And you probably need to go on and read the secondary literature named there.

Comment: Named mutexes are really intended to be used when you are coordinating *between* processes. Is that really your intention here?

Comment: Fildor: Does the application or other processes (parallel executed UnitTests for example) care about an abandoned mutex? 

@Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thats why it is used in unittests - TestMethods are executet parralely, not serially.

Comment: BTW: The docs discourage your usage of the constructor: "If name is not null and initiallyOwned is true, the calling thread owns the mutex only if the named system mutex was created as a result of this call. Since there is no mechanism for determining whether the named system mutex was created, it is better to specify false for initiallyOwned when calling this constructor overload. You can use the Mutex(Boolean, String, Boolean) constructor if you need to determine initial ownership."

Comment: Arno, in my *opinion* , if your tests have to use a mutex, you are doing something wrong. Either the code you are testing is unfit for tests of that sort or the test cases are designed badly.

Comment: @ArnoNym - they're executed in parallel but *within the same process*, unless you have a highly unusual setup.

Comment: Yes, it kind of is indeed. It should be an integration test, there is some serious file-reading and writing going on and that´s why I forced those unittest-methods to not run parallel

Comment: Hmm, I admit I am not too experienced with integration test design. But I would probably mock File I/O for those tests.

Comment: @Fidor&Damien_The_Unbeliever:
Can you please say something regarding sideeffects of any sort when using a named mutex?
Do other processes or even applications care about this mutex at all - abandoned and not?

Comment: Well, it is a System mutex, so there _could_ be sideeffects. I am not really sure, but I could imaginge that it could affect even two adjacent runs of the test suite ...

Comment: The least I would do to improve the situation is to resort to some alternative way of synchronization. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives

Comment: @Fildor: But it is explicitly named, why should any other part care? This is the big question for me :) I would totally understand if it would NOT be named or even if it has the "Global" prefix

Comment: "any other part" is one thing. My thought was that _the same part_ is going to care if the mutex is going to be abandoned in one run and a second run won't be able to create the mutex because it already exists ... And also I second Damien in that it is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: You should only care about the very questionable choice of keeping code running when such a nasty mishap occurred.  The deadlock or AME that is likely to be next will be quite hard to diagnose.  The code in the snippet is too fake to ever have such an outcome.

Comment: @Hans Passant: But will there even be a deadlock? The mutex is clearly only existing in this class, no other class or method refers to this mutex. So any other part of the application does not care at all, right?

Comment: Why did you use a named mutex?  The only reason is to allow *another process* to use the mutex as well, opening it by name.  That other process of course keeps running, it will misbehave when trying to use it.  So it deadlocks if you catch the exception, dies on AME if you let the exception terminate the thread or process.  The AME is a goody that is specific to Mutex, since you can't rely on it you do rather care.

Comment: You're definitely using the wrong tools here. You apparently have tests that cannot coexist with parallel executions - but you're only trying to protect that at the test level. If there are serious mutual exclusion issues to deal with, they should be dealt with *within those components* rather than relying on every caller knowing that they should queue up and not use your components in a parallel fashion. This seems doubly problematic in that these appear to be unit tests. Single-threaded code is going to become rare in the modern age.